# Combine XML nodes with different values for the same attribute using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
<text top="143" left="721" width="209" height="366" font="0">1</text>
<text top="222" left="608" width="221" height="52" font="1">Chapter 1</text>
<text top="481" left="171" width="488" height="71" font="2">Introduction to</text>
<text top="564" left="171" width="376" height="71" font="2">Information</text>
<text top="646" left="171" width="360" height="71" font="2">Technology</text>
<text top="731" left="171" width="387" height="31" font="3">Mind Tools for Your Future</text>
<text top="786" left="171" width="119" height="18" font="4">Key Questions</text>
<text top="813" left="171" width="344" height="10" font="5">You should be able to answer the following questions.</text>
<text top="840" left="171" width="19" height="10" font="5">1.1</text>
<text top="840" left="213" width="463" height="10" font="5">Infotech Becomes Commonplace: Cellphones, E-Mail, the Internet, &amp; the </text>
<text top="858" left="213" width="50" height="10" font="5">E-World </text>
<text top="856" left="265" width="568" height="13" font="6">How does information technology facilitate e-mail, networks, and the use of the Internet</text>
<text top="874" left="213" width="388" height="13" font="6">and the Web; what is the meaning of the term cyberspace?</text>
<text top="897" left="171" width="19" height="10" font="5">1.2</text>
```

The text nodes have 'height' attribute with different values. I want to group the text nodes according to height.

Expected Output:

```
<text>1</text>
<text>Chapter 1</text>
<text>Introduction to Information Technology</text>
<text>Mind Tools for Your Future</text>
<text>Key Questions</text>
<text>You should be able to answer the following questions. 1.1 Infotech Becomes Commonplace: Cellphones, E-Mail, the Internet, &amp; the E-World 1.2</text>
<text>How does information technology facilitate e-mail, networks, and the use of the Internet and the Web; what is the meaning of the term cyberspace?</text>
```

Is it possible to group the text nodes based on the following logic:
 - Group the elements having same height value until a new height value is encountered

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```html
<text>1</text>
<text>Chapter 1</text>
<text>Introduction to Information Technology</text>
<text>Mind Tools for Your Future</text>
<text>Key Questions</text>
<text>You should be able to answer the following questions. 1.1 Infotech Becomes Commonplace: Cellphones, E-Mail, the Internet, &amp; the E-World</text>
<text>How does information technology facilitate e-mail, networks, and the use of the Internet and the Web; what is the meaning of the term cyberspace?</text>
<text>1.2</text>
```

As seen for height=10, the text node

```html
<text>1.2</text>
```

is created again. It is not merged with the previous one.

Comment: Your input document is not well-formed - please edit your question to fix it. Also, you forgot to show the XSLT code you currently have.

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2.0, you will want to use xsl:for-each-group with the height attribute as the value of the group-by attribute, something like

```
<xsl:template match="unnamed-parent-element">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="text" group-by="@height">
    <xsl:sort select="number(@height)"/>
    <div>
      <head>Text elements whose height is 
        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
      </head>
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <!--* or do whatever you need to do with the
            * members of the group here ... *-->
      </
    </div>
  </
</
```

In XSLT 1.0, you will want to search for "Muenchian grouping" and read one of the many good discussions of the technique that can be found on the web, if only one knows the term to search for.